# How to add user roles?

Tags: user-roles

I need to build a news site with 16 user roles.

How can I add more user roles?

By default I see 4 roles:

- contributor
- author
- editor
- administrator

Comment: I prefer you can use plugin for creating roles because you have to do lots of work for setting the capability for each and every role. In wordpress Role and Capability page it suggest lots of pluging for the same

Comment: possible duplicate of [Adding New Role](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/178625/adding-new-role)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want is [`add_role()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_role)

The [Codex provides sample code](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_role#Example):

```
$result = add_role(
    'basic_contributor',
    __( 'Basic Contributor' ),
    array(
        'read'         => true,  // true allows this capability
        'edit_posts'   => true,
        'delete_posts' => false, // Use false to explicitly deny
    )
);
if ( null !== $result ) {
    echo 'Yay! New role created!';
}
else {
    echo 'Oh... the basic_contributor role already exists.';
}
```

Comment: ok but when i login to my site, i cannot open this `page wp-admin/profile.php`

Comment: I don't have any trouble getting to the profile page. Where do you have the code?

Answer (score 0):

I advice you to use a plugin for creating roles because you have to do lots of work for setting the capability for each and every role. In WordPress’ [Roles and Capabilities](http://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities) page it suggests lots of plugins for the same.