# Subscriber role - blank page

Tags: users, user-roles, capabilities

I did a fresh install of WP4.2 today, but after playing for a while with setting up a custom user roles I realized that the built-in subscriber role is returning blank page instead of the dashboard.

Do you have the same problem?

Comment: You forgot to assign the `view => true` to the user role. [Read more](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/178629/22728)

Comment: I would think so @MayeenulIslam, but the OP states "built-in subscriber role". Do you have [debugging information](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/95983/21376)?

Comment: @s_ha_dum good note. I somehow missed that. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer. It is because the WooCommerce plugin which prevents users without edit_posts capability to display dashboard.

Well, I think they should let you know that they are making this kind of change in WordPress default settings. Because you are not able to turn it off in WooCommerce settings.

Comment: I'm facing the same problem. Did you find a way to fix that?