# How to decipher the following array

Tags: array

I created a custom key and wanted to store multiple values in the key with an array in my plugin using a drop down box, however, I printed out the array and came back out with this value...

```
Array ( [0] => a:2:{i:0;s:2:"75";i:1;s:2:"68";} )
```

My thinking was that it would just add another value `[1] => 'content', [2] => 'lkajsdf'`. That is how I wanted it to happen, but instead I get the result above. It is storing the two ID values that I selected `75` and `68`.

So, what does that result mean?

Comment: PHP [`serialize()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) and [`unserialize()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php). Use [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net)'s tidyup button - a bogus but effective technique I mentioned [here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/178629/22728) :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're looking at a [serialized representation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8641889/how-to-use-php-serialize-and-unserialize) of the array `Array( '75', '68' )`. Serialization is the process by which PHP stores a data object as a string, much like the manner in which JSON is a string representation of a Javascript object. PHP data structures may be converted into a serialized format via PHP's [`serialize()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php), and back again using [`unserialize()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php).

WordPress also provides functions which perform the necessary action only when needed in order to prevent accidental double-serialization or unserialization: [`maybe_serialize()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/maybe_serialize) and [`maybe_unserialize()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/maybe_unserialize). You can also check yourself with WordPress' [`is_serialized()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_serialized).

From the comments on PHP's `serialize()`, the anatomy of a serialized data object is as follows:

> String `s:size:value;`
>
> Integer `i:value;`
>
> Boolean `b:value;` (does not store `"true"` or `"false"`, does store `1` or
>   `0`)
>
> Null `N;`
>
> Array `a:size:{key definition;value definition;(repeated per element)}`
>
> Object `O:strlen(object name):object name:object`
>
> size `s:strlen(property name):property name:property definition;(repeated per property)`
>
> String values are always in double quotes.
>
> Array keys are always integers or strings; using other types as keys produces undesirable results:
>
> - `null => 'value'` equates to `'s:0:"";s:5:"value";'`
> - `true => 'value'` equates to `'i:1;s:5:"value";'`
> - `false => 'value'` equates to `'i:0;s:5:"value";'`
> - `array(whatever the contents) => 'value'` equates to an "illegal offset type" warning because you can't use an array as a key; however, if you use a variable containing an array as a key, it will equate to `'s:5:"Array";s:5:"value";'`, and attempting to use an object as a key will result in the same behavior as using an array will.

Therefore, we can interpret your particular serialized array `a:2:{i:0;s:2:"75";i:1;s:2:"68";}` as such:

- `a:2:{` an array of length 2, containing:

  - `i:0;` at the integer key `0` (i.e. index `0`):

    - `s:2:"75";` a string of length 2 with the value "75"
  - `i:1;` at the integer key `1` (i.e. index `1`):

    - `s:2:"68"` a string of length 2 with the value "68"
- `}` end of the array

To alternately reflect the values of your items `'content'` and `'lkajsdf'` rather than their numerical identifiers, then, the array `Array( 'content', 'lkajsdf' )` would be serialized as

`a:2:{i:0;s:7:"content";i:1;s:7:"lkajsdf";}`

Knowing this can come in handy if you ever need to alter some of WordPress's settings, or selectively activate/deactivate specific plugins directly from the database.

Comment: We've all run into the question at one point or another ;) . I think perhaps the most important thing to keep in mind with WordPress and serialization is that WordPress stores some data in the database as a serialized string. If you ever go to perform a search-and-replace operation on your WordPress database, think twice, because it may well invalidate any serialized data containing that string. There are a few serialization-aware database search-and-replace tools for that reason.

Comment: +1 good overview and I like how you break up the serialized string with comments, similar to how regexp patterns are often explained.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the your multiple values were simply serialized by PHP's [`serialize()` function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php).

You can unserialize it with [`unserialize()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php).

Answer (score 0):

After unserializing the result is:

```
Array
(
   [0] => 75
   [1] => 68
)
```

You can find the format of PHP serialized array here: [Serialized PHP string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14297926/structure-of-a-serialized-php-string)

`a:2` is object array here
`'s':<i>` is the string where i is the length of string